# GCH in $L[A]$ when $A\subset \omega_1$

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to prove the GCH in the constructible universe $L[A]$ when $A$ is a subset of the ordinal $\omega_1$. For this purpouse, first I want to see that if we take any elementary substructe $X\prec L_\alpha[A]$ then its Mostowski collapse $M$ is $L_\beta[B]$ where $\beta=o(M)$ and $B=\pi[A\cap X]$.

In this regard I want to ask if the following equivalence is true for transitive models $M$

$$(V=L[A])^M\Leftrightarrow M=L_\beta[A^M]$$

where $\beta=o(M)$ is the first ordinal not in $M$ and $A^M$ is the interpretation in $M$ of the predicate $A$. If it is true, then by elementarity and sice $A^M$ in this case is $\pi[A\cap X]$, the result would be clear for me. If it is not the case, could you show me an argument which proves my initial claim?

Thank You.

Comment: This equivalence is called condensation.

Comment: In case that isn't clear from Asaf's comment: This equivalence is indeed true and can be proved by a straightforward generalization of the usual condensation lemma. Since the case for limit ordinals suffices and is (depending on your approach) easier to manage, you may want to prove it only for limit ordinals $\beta$.

Comment: Regarding the equivalence, is the following reasoning right? Left to right: If $(V=L[A])^M$ then $\forall x\in M\;\exists\delta<o(M)\;(x\in (L_\delta[A])^M)$ and since $\delta\mapsto L_\delta[A]$ is $\Delta_1$ then $(L_\delta[A])^M=L_\delta[A^M]$. So $M\subset L_\beta[A^M]$. For the other inclusion, once again by absoluteness, $L_\delta[A^M]=(L_\delta[A])^M$. Then if $x\in L_\beta[A^M]$ then $x\in L_\delta[A^M]=(L_\delta[A])^M\in M$ and therefor $L_\beta[A^M]\subset M$.

Comment: In brief, my question is: Supposing $\delta\in M$ then $L_\delta[A^M]=(L_\delta[A])^M$?

Comment: @Ergonvi Yes, that's true. And you're right that $\delta \mapsto L_\delta[A]$ is $\Delta_1$ (modulo some weak set theory). The "weak set theory" part is what hinders this proof to work if $o(M)$ is a successor ordinal.